# react-image-crop not cropped image properly

Tags: reactjs, cropper, react-image-crop

I am using [react-image-crop](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-image-crop) to cropped my images and show the final result.

when I am try using below code then my image not render properly

```
<ReactCrop src={src} onImageLoaded={setImage} crop={crop} onChange={setCrop} />
```

but if I am try this code to cropped my image

```
<ReactCrop crop={crop} onChange={setCrop}> <img src={props.imageUrl} onLoad={setImage} alt="crop" /></ReactCrop>
```

my image show properly and cropper image but when I am trying to save image it's show me error (mention in below line)
**Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLCanvasElement or HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas or SVGImageElement or VideoFrame)'.**

```
   import { useState } from 'react';
    import ReactCrop from 'react-image-crop';
    import 'react-image-crop/dist/ReactCrop.css';
    
    function ImageCropper() {
        const [src, setSrc] = useState(null);
        const [crop, setCrop] = useState({ aspect: 16 / 9 });
        const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
        const [output, setOutput] = useState(null);
    
        const selectImage = (file) => {
            setSrc(URL.createObjectURL(file));
        };
    
        const cropImageNow = () => {
            const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            const scaleX = image.naturalWidth / image.width;
            const scaleY = image.naturalHeight / image.height;
            canvas.width = crop.width;
            canvas.height = crop.height;
            const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    
            const pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio;
            canvas.width = crop.width * pixelRatio;
            canvas.height = crop.height * pixelRatio;
            ctx.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
            ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';
    
            ctx.drawImage(
                image,
                crop.x * scaleX,
                crop.y * scaleY,
                crop.width * scaleX,
                crop.height * scaleY,
                0,
                0,
                crop.width,
                crop.height,
            );
    
            // Converting to base64
            const base64Image = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
            setOutput(base64Image);
        };
    
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <center>
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        accept="image/*"
                        onChange={(e) => {
                            selectImage(e.target.files[0]);
                        }}
                    />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        {src && (
                            <div>
                                   <ReactCrop crop={crop} onChange={setCrop}>
                      <img src={src} onLoad={setImage} alt="crop" />
                    </ReactCrop>
                                <br />
                                <button onClick={cropImageNow}>Crop</button>
                                <br />
                                <br />
                            </div>
                        )}
                    </div>
                    <div>{output && <img src={output} />}</div>
                </center>
            </div>
        );
    }
    export default ImageCropper;
```

Comment: There is a proper way to add your code to the question Kindly explore!
Ane the official doc has the latter syntax that you mentioned
`<ReactCrop crop={crop} onChange={c => setCrop(c)}>
      <img src={src} />
    </ReactCrop>`

Comment: @Nishanth kindly look at the below in my question where I am add my code these line are just for helping that I am trying